# I'm getting errors about expected indentifiers and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, string

Actually the following program is a module of my actual program and I get expected identifier errors in this code.

```
class New
{

    static void check(String m)
    {
        int start=0,end=0;
        char ch[]=m.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<m.length();i++)
        {
            start=end;
            if(ch[i]==32)
            {
                end=i;
                break;
            }
            count(ch,start,end);
         }
      }

      static void count(char chq[],int initial,int final)
      {
          //String s=new String(chq,initial,final);
          System.out.println(initial+" is Initial");
          System.out.println(final+" is final");
      }

      public static void main(String... s)
      {
          String k="India is a Good Nation. I Love my India";
          check(k);
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the *exact* error? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: I am expecting for "India" in the output for the first time. But the code is not even compiled

Comment: **Why not**? What error do you get? Did you read it?

Comment: Absolutely useless. "Certain errors in this code" and "Some Identifier expectations" convey precisely nothing.

Comment: You can start renaming `final` to anything but a reserved word.

Comment: That is a ver very bad question. Couldn't you just read your certain errors or at least Google them?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of you are using final as a parameter name in count method. final is a keyword in java which can not be used as a parameter name or variable name. Try -

```
static void count(char chq[],int initial, final int end)
{
     //String s=new String(chq,initial,final);
     System.out.println(initial+" is Initial");
     System.out.println(end+" is final");
 }
```

instead of

```
  static void count(char chq[],int initial,int final)
  {
      //String s=new String(chq,initial,final);
      System.out.println(initial+" is Initial");
      System.out.println(final+" is final");
  }
```